# What is isogonal family of a given family of curves?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

I searched in Wikipedia  [isogonal trajectories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_trajectory#Isogonal_trajectory)  about the definition but I do not understand what does it mean by fixed "angle". Angle with the tangents of the curves? Clockwise angle? Orientated Angle? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An isogonal trajectory is a plane curve intersecting the curves of a given one-parameter family in the plane *at one and the same angle*.

If

[image]

is the differential equation of the given family of curves, then an isogonal trajectory of this family intersecting it at an angle α, where $0<α<π$, $α≠π/2$, satisfies one of the following two equations:

[image]

In particular, the equation

[image]

is satisfied by an orthogonal trajectory, that is, a plane curve that forms a right angle at each of its points with any curve of the family (1) passing through it. The orthogonal trajectories for the given system (1) form a one-parameter family of plane curves — the **general integral** of equation (1). For example, if the family of lines of force of a plane electrostatic field is considered, then the family of orthogonal trajectories are the equipotential lines.

Here is another example of isogonal (and orthogonal) trajectory:

[image]

P.s. The word isogonal derives from the ancient Greek, *isos* = equal, and *gon* = angle, as seen in the English word *knee*, which forms an angle in a leg!

**References**: W.W. [V.V. Stepanov] Stepanow, "Lehrbuch der Differentialgleichungen" , Deutsch. Verlag Wissenschaft. (1956) (Translated from Russian)

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  but my concern is that if the angle is not right,  then there are 2 possibilities for a tangent and therefor 2 isogonal trajectories for each family of curves.

Comment: @dmtri The angle is fixed between 0 and π, so the tangent may be positive or negative. However, it is enough that the angle satisfies one of the two equations above for the isogonal trajectory to be verified

Comment: Maybe this example could help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_trajectory#Isogonal_trajectory

Answer (score 1):

I think that for two curves $y=f(x)$ and $y=g(x)$ which intersect at $(x_0,y_0)$, they are defining the angle between the curves to be $\ \mathrm{arctan}(f'(x_0)) - \mathrm{arctan}(g'(x_0))$.

Comment: Why not $\mathrm{arctan}g'(x_0) - \mathrm{arctan}f'(x_0)$ , if I may ask?